# Facebook app being throttled, what is gr:post:User/external_edge

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, throttling

Our app is currently being throttled, we are getting

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 4
  }
}
```

On `App`->`Insights`->`Developer`->`Activity & Errors` we are seeing

```
Restrictions
App is unrestricted.

API Throttling
None during specified period.
```

So it doesn't look like we should be getting throttled, but I *can* see a warning,

```
Calls Are Too CPU Intensive  - 2 hours, 38 minutes
Method  Fraction of Budget

gr:post:User/external_edge  109%
gr:post:User/scores 1.8%
gr:get:User/external_edge   1.8%
gr:get:/fql 1.2%
ui:feed:async:get:  0.43%
gr:post:OpenGraphAction/commen  0.15%
ui:apprequests:iframe:get:  0.08%
gr:delete:Post  0.04%
gr:delete:  0.02%
ui:feed:async:post: 0.02%
```

I assume this means that we're posting too often to User/external_edge... but I don't know what User/external_edge is -- how do I find this out?

Also shouldn't we have gotten an email or warning before being cut off from the API? What do we need to do to get unthrottled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits reset automatically after a while, i think it's a 600 second rolling window for calculation of the limit, but might extend the blocking to 3600seconds if the limit is actually reached; Unfortunately there's no way in the API response to see how close you are to the CPU and call limits, and the CPU limit in particular is hard to predict because calls have vastly varying resources needed to process them.

`gr:post:User/external_edge` is Open Graph actions, the other methods are named after the name of the connection (e.g. `gr:post:User/scores` is a Graph API (`gr`) POST request (`post`) against the `scores` connection of the `User` object)

If your app is being throttled on these and you're not posting a large number of actions per user, check which access token is being used to make the posts; if it's an App Access Token, use the User Access Token for the user making the posts instead

Comment: Thanks Igy. Should being throttled on post:User/external_edge be blocking simple get calls to fbid?fields=id,name,installed as well? Would have been nice to be able to fix this w/o our app grinding to a halt because getting users' friends' names is failing.

Comment: I'm not actually sure exactly what 'switch' trips when you go over the limit and how that affects different API calls until it resets: as far as I'm aware the limits most likely to be reached are calculated as a `<user, app>` pairing, and not across the entire app - check that you're using user access tokens wherever possible

Comment: Ah, good catch. We are using the app access token to post open graph stories so that users can't forge them. I guess we'll have to forego that security. The simple reads that are being blocked are being requested with user access tokens though.

Comment: @Igy - since this is the only question relevant... we have the same thing but our is gr:get:User/likes making 100% , is that only for graph api calls , or would that include <fb:Like calls that are checking if like was performed to render button ??

Comment: The like button plugin shouldn't be affecting your API call logs or limits as far as I know; if you have a lot of calls to gr:Get:User/likes in your insights it's probably because you're checking if a user likes a specific page, or retrieving their full list of likes