# Facebook OpenGraph Calls are Too CPU Intensive

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In my Facebook app I'm getting the following warnings:
gr:post:User/external_edge  115%

Error Code 1611072 (Action Requires at least one reference: The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects.
At least one of the following properties must be specified:
{property_names}.

I've read posts saying to use the User Access Token and not the App Access Token for OpenGraph request which we are already doing.

Not sure what the issue here is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923429/facebook-app-being-throttled-what-is-grpostuser-external-edge may have some additional insight into the weird `gr:post:User/external_edge 115%` thing.

Comment: Yeah that's the post that suggests using the User Access Token which we already are. Just seems like we're getting conflicting errors between CPU intensity and {property_names}